# Where can I download mysqlcheck.exe? (wamp 2.5)

Tags: mysql, wamp

I'm using wamp server 2.5.
I need the mysqlcheck.exe program, where can I download it?
Googled it, all that came up were those sketchy "download dll files" websites, I'd rather download it from a reliable place.
Thanks

Comment: There is no way you can say if a place you want to download something from is trustworthy or not. How do you want to decide that? By looking at the domain name? Or by how professional the site looks? You are facing one of the major problems with the MS-Windows platform: the lack of a software management system as it exists for other operating systems. MS is master of "copying" ideas from others, I have no idea why they failed to implement this absolutely essential detail for an operating system.

Comment: But, who made the mysqlcheck program? Wouldn't there be an "official page" for it or something?

Comment: And how do you know if some page really is "their" page?

Comment: MySQL.org, but the question is off topic.

Answer (score 2):

I found it!

it's included in MySQL Server which can be installed from MySQL Installer which can be downloaded at

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

then, it's in the "bin" folder of the MySQL Server installation, i.e.

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqlcheck"

on my install.

also includes "mysqldump" and all the rest.

Comment: Oops, it was also in "wamp/bin/mysql/*version*/bin"